# Creating a client editable events calendar in html or php

Tags: php, html, wordpress, calendar

A prospective client wants to have a calendar feature on their website. They want the option to go edit this calendar to update the events. Does Word Press offer something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen people use Google Calendar for this.  Then you can easily embed google cal in your web pages.  Also, if others use Google Cal they can add evens to their calendars.

http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41207

Update:  Looks like this plugin will help with getting google cal into Wordpress if that's what you're looking for :

[WoogleCal](http://www.blueace.nl/wooglecal/)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be searching for [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/event-calendar/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Wordpress has that feature but I do know of a Calendar class for PHP that's fairly simple, easy to implement and very easy to style. Check out the tutorial, [here](http://oscarm.org/page/calendarClass/).

Answer (score 0):

There is also a PEAR package for calendaring: http://pear.php.net/package/calendar

Answer (score 0):

I second the embeddable Google Calendar. They are very easy to manage as well as add it to the HTML. If you are looking for a Wordpress specific solution in particular take a look at [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/calendar/).